# never reach 100% in Genetic algorithm

Tags: c++, genetic-algorithm

My Main Program, i think thats all correctly, can anyone tell me where my mistake, i have never got 100% fitness

i was, frustated about it, please answer me if you know

```
void mutate(population *parent,int ratio){

for(unsigned int i=0; i<sizeof(parent[0].gen); i++){
    int condition = (rand()%11);
    int temp0 = (int)parent[0].gen[i];
    int temp1 = (int)parent[1].gen[i];

    if(condition < ratio){
        if(temp0+10 <127 ){
            parent[0].gen[i] = char(temp0 + 10);
            //cout<<temp0<<endl;
        }else{
            temp0 = temp0 + 10 - 80;
            parent[0].gen[i] = char(temp0);
           // cout<<(int)parent[0].gen[i]<<endl;
        }

        if(temp1+10 <127 ){
            parent[1].gen[i] = char(temp1 + 10);
            //cout<<temp0<<endl;
        }else{
            temp1 = temp1 + 10 - 80;
            parent[1].gen[i] = char(temp1);
        }
    }
}
```

this is my sample code for mutation, complete program in picture below

[GeneticAlgorithm_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dB6I3.png)
[GeneticAlgorithm_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ie0Od.png)

Comment: I think you need to study neural networks and genetic algorithms some more. Obtaining a 100% success rate is impossible.

Comment: Please expand on when and why you think you should achieve 100%.

Comment: Your question seems interesting. Unfortunately, the screenshots are useless for us, and you should better describe the expected result and why you think that a 100% should be achieved when your loop condition seems to be designed to stop with a lower quality.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question what kind of problem you are solving, but most likely it is NP-completeness, other types can be solved much more efficient without machine learning. But you must understand that the exact solution for [NP-completeness problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness) requires exhaustive search of **all possible solutions**. Machine learning cannot avoid this problem, so the achievement of 100% accuracy nothing easier time than brutfors based methods. The goal of machine learning and in particular genetic algorithms is to find an **acceptable** solution in a **acceptable time**.

Comment: Welcome ! While your statement is not wrong, it doesn't answer the question at all.  By the way, [genetic algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) are not necessarily machine learning. They have often more to do with optimisation although they can be used for [optimising learning](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/understanding-genetic-algorithms-in-the-artificial-intelligence-spectrum-7021b7cc25e7).  Furthermore they have proven to be very effective for some problems in which traditional algorithms can't cope with combinatorial explosion.